# Top homology of pure algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Given a pure-dimensional complex projective variety X, it is well-known that its top homology $H_{top}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is freely generated by fundamental cycles of its irreducible components. What is the standard reference for this fact? (i.e. book, page number)

Comment: I am not sure about a textbook reference, but take a look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393326/top-cohomology-and-irreducible-components/2393747#2393747). Also check Griffiths-Harris or/and Goresky-MacPherson. My answer refers to Hironaka's paper, but, likely, there is a simpler proof.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your answer already, but I was hoping for a textbook reference :) By "Goresky-MacPherson" I guess you mean the "Stratified
Morse Theory" book?

Comment: Yes..............